# How to Left and Right Align labels on UITableCell

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I need a table layout like this screenshot

I am using `UIStoryboard` and ARC

[image]   Screen:1

but i am getting like this

[image]  Screen:2

after scrolling the table it becomes like the first screen as required but initially its like screen 2.

My code for this in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method is

```
    UILabel *titleLabel = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:1];
titleLabel.backgroundColor  =[UIColor whiteColor];

if (indexPath.row % 2) {
    NSLog(@"Odd Cell");
    [titleLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(100.0f, 10.0f, 200.0f, 20.0f)];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Even Cell");
    [titleLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(20.0f, 10.0f, 200.0f, 20.0f)];
}
```

`titleLabel` is a label on the cell through IB and having the tag:1

I have to set the frame of label accordingly and then set the text in it not the text alignment.

thats why I set `titleLabel.backgroundColor  =[UIColor whiteColor];`

Comment: the frames of your even and uneven ones are exactly the same

Comment: @TimothyGroote no ... pls see the x coordinate in both the conditions...

Comment: do u trying to implement chat or chat conversasion??

Comment: no its just the design that alternative cells are aligned in this mannner.

Comment: what NSLog you are getting?

Comment: Even Cell
Odd Cell
Even Cell
Odd Cell
Even Cell
Odd Cell
Even Cell
Odd Cell

Answer (score 1):

Try this... its working

```
- (int)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *) tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (int) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 20;
}

-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell;

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"MainCell"];

    UILabel *titleLabel = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:1];
    titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 30)];

    CGRect labelPosition;
    if ((indexPath.row+1) % 2) {
        NSLog(@"Odd Cell");

        titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Odd Cell - %d", (indexPath.row+1)];
        titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Even Cell");
        labelPosition = titleLabel.frame;
        labelPosition.origin.x = 110;
        titleLabel.frame = labelPosition;
        titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Even Cell - %d", (indexPath.row+1)];
        titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    }
    titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    [cell addSubview:titleLabel];

    return cell;

}
```

### [Download test project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/89v51dch8uysfqt/test.zip)

Comment: Thanks its working very nice but I already achieved this and seen this after answering my own question, but your answer is also the good solution.

Comment: the problem with my code was dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier and you are not using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier but if we replace your top 2 lines of cellForRowAtIndexPath with dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier pattern like top 2 lines of cellForRowAtIndexPath with     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];   then the problem will encounter, you can check

Answer (score 1):

I have achieved this with a simple basic idea, and the code for this is

```
    UILabel *leftTitleLabel = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:1];
leftTitleLabel.backgroundColor  =[UIColor whiteColor];

UILabel *rightTitleLabel = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:2];
rightTitleLabel.backgroundColor  =[UIColor whiteColor];


if (indexPath.row % 2) {
    leftTitleLabel.hidden = YES;
    rightTitleLabel.hidden = NO;
    rightTitleLabel.text = @"Right Cell";
} else {
    rightTitleLabel.hidden = YES;
    leftTitleLabel.hidden = NO;
    leftTitleLabel.text = @"Left Cell";
}
```

Now there are 2 labels on the cell on required locations and set tags 1 n 2.

Comment: @IronManGill : I think this is ugly in look but better solution. In my answer, I am not using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier, means I am not **re-using**, everytime creating new, which is bad. can you have more better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use this : `cell.textLabel.textAlignment = ALIGN_CENTER;` &

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_6_0
#define ALIGN_CENTER NSTextAlignmentCenter
#else
#define ALIGN_CENTER UITextAlignmentCenter
#endif
```

Comment: And if he wants it not in the center but 20 px before it then ?

Comment: Then its not center. You have to set frame as per your requirements.

Comment: Exactly... so he didn't mention the center did he ?

Comment: Center is just for example. You can use same for Left or Right alignment.

Comment: @Developer : why you are posting different different answer? Edit your first answer and put all there... **Keep SO Clean**

Answer (score 0):

In cellForRowAtIndexPath method

```
    UILabel *titleLabel = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:1];
titleLabel.backgroundColor  =[UIColor whiteColor];

if (indexPath.row % 2) {
    NSLog(@"Odd Cell");
    titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
} else {
    NSLog(@"Even Cell");
    titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft; 
}
```

Comment: I have to set the frame of label when table first loaded not the text alignment.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom cell. And re-implement layoutSubview function. Something like that

```
@synthesize padding;
-(void)layoutSubview {
    [super layoutSubview];

    [self.titleLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(padding, 10.0f, 200.0f, 20.0f)];
}
```

and cellForRowAtIndexPath function:

```
if (indexPath.row % 2) {
    NSLog(@"Odd Cell");
    [cell setPadding:100.f];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Even Cell");
    [cell setPadding:20.f];
}
```